# How to send the recepients local time in mails ?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, email, datetime

I have to send the local time of the recipient in the body of a e-mail. The body of my email is html content. And am passing some variables like date etc in the html body through my c# code. Is there any format of DateTime that I can pass which will be automatically converted to local time by the mailbox or something that I can do in html/javascript which will dynamically convert the time into recepients local time when the mail is received?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **no**, sorry. You would either need to store the **time-zone** of each user in a database somewhere, and then your C# code would provide a time offset by a certain number of hours, e.g:

```
<%=MyDate.AddHours(Subscriber.TimeZoneOffset)%>
```

As for your idea of executing JavaScript in the e-mail body: *not gonna happen !!*

Being a lazy sort, I would probably just settle for qualifying all times in my e-mail(s) like **09:00 GMT/CET/PST**. I realise this might not be acceptable for all use-cases, though ;)

Comment: We can store the timezone information of the user when he last logs in but what if the last time he logged in is from a different timezone than the place where he opens the mail. Its certainly not efficient. I guess if there's no other way then I would have to go with just displaying GMT beside the date time :(

Comment: Well, that's what I would call an *edge case*. Most of your users live and work in the same time-zone, no? What you have just suggested is a really clever way to solve the problem. Kudos.

Comment: I would store the user's timezone in the profile if possible and use that to convert on the server.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a no go in sent e-mails, since it's not executed on the clients for security reasons. Therefore, the time must be added to the mail when sent.

Do you have the users timezone, ZIP code or country short code in your DB? Or, alternatively, are the users logged in when sending the e-mail? In that case, you can just do the math on the server, using that data.

If you don't hold their timezone information beforehand, you can't definitely convert to their local time.